# Hibernate Search object to string bridge

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm using Infinispan 6.0.2 and Hibernate Search 4.4.0.

In my cache, there are some data which value is `hibernate_search_DSL` (type **String**). When I use keyword search with `hibernate`, it can't find the result with underscore (`hibernate_search_DSL`).

I think in Hibernate `hibernate_search_DSL` is just one word, so I wrote a String Bridge try to replace all `_` to **space**, but it doesn't work.

Here is my class:

```
public class NormaliseValue implements StringBridge{

    public String objectToString(Object object)
    {
        if(object == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no value to normalise");

        String value = object.toString();
        value.replaceAll("_", " ");
        return value;
    }
}
```

And mapping index:

```
mapping.entity(Hibernate.class).indexed().providedId()
    .property("value", ElementType.FIELD).field().bridge(NormaliseValue.class);
```

Is something wrong or there is any solution simpler to find result with underscore???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour is to use the StandardAnalyzer, which breaks input strings on whitespaces and symbols.
So the literal "hibernate_search_DSL" is probably (I assume you're using the default analyzer)  tokenized into the different keywords "hibernate", "search" and "dsl" (as it also does lowercasing).

The principle of full-text is that then when you tokenize the query via the same Analyzer, it will match and score according the to parts.

If you want to disable this and just use an exact-match, disable the Analyzer on the property with the annotation:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
```

Comment: Ty for the reponse. But the **hibernate_search_DSL** is already indexed and stored in the Infinispan Cache. I used the "StandardAnalyzer" and what I want to do is search the word **hibernate** and find the **hibernate_search_DSL** in the result. In my system, it doesn't work. So I want to write a bridge to transform the **hibernate_search_DSL** to "hibernate", "search" and "dsl". I think if it stores the values like 3 word, I can find the ID who has **hibernate_search_DSL** through keyword **hibernate**. @Sanne

Comment: I compared my StringBridge with the example in Hibernate Reference Guide, But I can't find where is the problem. The value in the cache didn't change after I use the bridge.

Comment: yes the standardanalyzer should split it. This will only affect the index, not the cache content! And of course if you made the change after the data was stored, you'll have to rebuild the index.

Comment: But if it was indexed by 3 words "hibernate", "search" and "dsl", why the `query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("value").matching("hibernate").creatQuery();` found nothing. Like u said, there is no need to write this bridge?? @Sanne

Comment: I don't know how it was indexed, that depends on the Analyzer you have configured. The best way to inspect the index contents is to use Luke: https://code.google.com/p/luke/ always helpfull to debug such situations.